# A more logical way to tackle this probability question

Tags: probability

A student goes to college either by car,scooter,bus,train . Probability of each being $\frac {1}{7},\frac {3}{7},\frac {2}{7},\frac {1}{7} $ respectively. The probability that he reaches college late if he takes car ,scooter,bus or train is $\frac {2}{9},\frac {1}{9},\frac {4}{9},\frac {1}{9} $ resp. If he reached college in time ,the probability that he travelled by car is?. I know the answer is  $\frac {1}{7}$ using bayes theorem but I want to know a more logical way to solve which does not involve any formula.

Comment: I think the Bayes theorem is already a very logical way to explain the issue. The ratio between the probabilities of the way of travelling he chosen given he reached college in time is $1\times(9-2):3\times(9-1):2\times(9-4):1\times(9-1) = 7:24:10:8$. Essentially you partitioned the event of reach in time into 4 scenarios. And then by normalizing you obtain the result, the conditional probability.

Comment: No like can you link this idea with a venn diagram or something

Comment: If you're allergic to the mathematical formula for Bayes' Theorem, you might imagine a population of 6300 trips, make an appropriate table (with columns for modes of transportation and rows for on time and not), and count.